# Making a dynamic graph on a HTML webpage that pulls data from a txt file

Tags: php, html, dynamic, charts

I am building a webpage that I want to have a dynamic chart shown to the user. Similar to https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/ . The webpage needs to pull the data from a txt file, and then update the graph as time goes. The txt file is eventually going to be having data written to it, and I want to be able to plot the data from the txt file to the webpage as it comes in. I have looked around, and https://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/how-can-i-plot-values-from-txt-file/ describes the issue I am facing. 
The txt file has values of (to keep it simple):
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

The code I am trying to run is below, but whenever I open the HTML inside a browser, the screen is blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var dataPoints = [];

//Replace text file's path according to your requirement.
$.get("testgraph.txt", function(data) {
    var x = 0;
    var allLines = data.split('\n');
    if(allLines.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
            dataPoints.push({x: x , y: parseInt(allLines[i])});
            x += .25;
        }
    }
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title :{
            text: "Chart using Text File Data"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints : dataPoints,
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm very confused as to why when I open the browser the screen is blank. The text file is called testgraph.txt and is saved on my desktop (I use Windows 10). And the html file is called test.html and is also saved on my desktop. Any ideas would be very helpful, as I am lost at this point. The end goal is to have numerical numbers coming into the text file, read by the webpage, and then update the graph dynamically.

Thanks,
Tyler

Comment: Did you check for errors in the browser console? As you are on windows 10 it seems unlikely to me that the path to canvasjs is valid.

Comment: What do you mean errors in the browser console?

Comment: In firefox: menu -> Web Developer ->  Web Console (or ctrl+shift+k); in Chrome: menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools (or ctrl+shift+i). Should be easy to find in Edge or IE. It will open a developer panel; the Console tab shows errors, warnings, etc. Here's the [doc for firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools); the others would be readily available with an internet search.

Comment: Awesome- thanks. I will check that out and get back to you. And the “testgraph.txt” doesn’t need to have the directory or anything in it correct? It should find the txt file if it’s on the desktop correct?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus - This is the error I'm getting from the Dev Tools:

SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined

Comment: Got it working - had to download CanvasJS files and put them into the folder so the HTML knew what to look for. Thanks for the help! @DinoCoderSaurus